# How to change return results fields names when called SP in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am going call Stored procedure in another stored procedure. But I want change results return fields names to different. How can I change them?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_GetMembership]  
    @id varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        exec sp_Membership @id
END
```

When I called `exec sp_Membership @id` I will get below fields names. I want to change them

```
product_code    rate_structure  line_status_code    cycle_begin_date    cycle_end_date  initial_begin_date
PROFESSIONAL    1CATO30         P                   2012-01-01         2012-12-31       1994-08-01
```

Comment: In SQL Server 2008: no luck, sorry - unless you can change the source of the stored procedure. With SQL Server 2012, you'll [get some tools (a `WITH RESULT SETS` option for executing stored procs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/04/28/sql-server-denali-executing-stored-procedure-with-result-sets/) to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to load pre-created temporary table

```
..

CREATE TABLE #foo  (..)

INSERT #foo
exec sp_Membership @id

SELECT * FROM #foo

...
```

Or modify `sp_Membership`

Or handle it in the client code